# Understanding generic methods

Tags: java, generics

I want to call the following method :

```
<C extends Iterable<R>> C as(Class<C> container)
```

(Anyone familiar with spring-data-neo4j will recognize this as a method of the [EndResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/conversion/EndResult.html)
class).

I'm not entirely comfortable with generics yet, and I don't understand how to call this method.

```
ArrayList<Point> pointlist = neo4jtemplate.findAll(Line.class).as( ?? );
```

the `findAll()` method returns an iterable of basic Neo4j "nodes", and chaining the `.as()`. method to it converts that result into an iterable of another type. If I wanted to convert it to an iterable of (for example)`Point` objects, how would I call this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `container` must be a Class object of a class that implements the `Iterable` interface for the type `R`. For example:

```
neo4jtemplate.findAll(Line.class).as(MyClassThatIteratesOverTypeR.class);
```

If the Iterable type is `Point`, perhaps:

```
class PointIterator implements Iterable<Point> {
    // you would have to implement all the method of Iterator
}
```

or simply:

```
class PointIterator extends ArrayList<Point> { } // That's all you need
```

then:

```
neo4jtemplate.findAll(Line.class).as(PointIterator.class);
```

---

Note that generics don't allow you to create a typed literal:

```
neo4jtemplate.findAll(Line.class).as(ArrayList<R>.class); // can't do this
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. In case it helps anyone else: Your suggestion requires me to then implement `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()`, which would be a waste of code given that I don't need any special functionality. So, my final solution was to simply extend `ArrayList` in my custom iterator class. works like a charm. will accept your answer when i can.

Comment: Yes, extending `class PointIterator extends ArrayList<Point> {}` is the easiest way to go. I should have put that in the answer, which I have just done :)